# How to do this step in IIS7, described via IIS6

Tags: iis-7, iis-6

Good afternoon.

If this was IIS6 I would do the following.

Right click on the relevant website and choose properties.

Click the Home Directory tab.

Click the configuration... button

The bottom window titled 'Wildcard application maps' needs an entry so I would click the Insert... button.  Browse to a file and untick veryify file exists.

I cannot find the equivalent steps in IIS7.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's under 'handler mappings' in IIS7. Select the website you want to configure and handler mappings should be an option.

Comment: That was the step I was looking for, since then I have had one error after another, it's the same site!  So am I missing something,  all ive done is publish the site from VS2008 and copied over to IIS7 and created the site entry in IIS7,  since then nothing but errors.  Am i meant to perhaps perform a different kind of publish that I am as yet unaware of?

Comment: Have you checked everything is enabled in IIS7? Like ASP.NET and anything else you might use?

Comment: Sorry yes we are looking good,  I am getting the error occurs when the step above has not worked. The site gets stuck in a redirect loop and registering that aspnet_isap.dll in IIS6 solves the problem. I would say i have not replicated the same behaviour in IIS7.

Answer (score 0):

This would be better asked on serverfault.com. stachoverflow is for coding questions.